# Dynamic columns in R dataframes

Tags: r, indexing

I'm playing with R dataframes, and trying to figure out how they work.
In the sample below, I'm trying to use a 1 row data frame to de-dup the elements of a vector.  I know there are much better ways to do this, like unique(), or use the hash library, etc, etc.  This is more about learning how the dataframe works.

This first part works just fine, if the column name being added is a string:

```
> v = c(1, 2, 3, 10, 100, 50, 50, 100, 1, 2, 3, 10)
> d = data.frame(row.names=c('the row'))
> d
data frame with 0 columns and 1 rows
> for (x in v) { d[1,as.character(x)] = x}
> d
        1 2 3 10 100 50
the row 1 2 3 10 100 50
```

However, if I try to use a number as a column name, I get very strange behaviour:

```
> e = data.frame(row.names=c('the row'))
> for (x in v) { e[1,x] = x}
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, 1, x, value = 10) : 
  new columns would leave holes after existing columns
> e
        V1 V2 V3
the row  1  2  3
```

First of all, where did 'V1', 'V2', and 'V3' come from?  Secondly, why doesn't this work?  I mean, I can sort of work out that it's not happy that 10 is not the next number after 3, but other than that I don't know why this doesn't work.

Are columns only indexable as strings? Other restrictions that are worth knowing about?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a note: in your first example, `d[,"10"]` and `d[,4]` refer to the same column.

Comment: `?data.frame` has a link to `?make.names`, which will probably help.

Comment: You answered your own question: `[<-.data.frame` won't extend a data frame by more than one column at a time. Since `e[,10]` refers to the 10th column, and you only have 3, no go.

Comment: Other restrictions? You may find this reading useful: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.data.frame.html. There you can read about e.g. what @joran pointed out: "The replacement methods can be used to add whole column(s) by specifying non-existent column(s), in which case the column(s) are added at the right-hand edge of the data frame and _numerical indices must be contiguous to existing indices_."

Comment: my understanding is...All columns in a data.frame have names; V1, etc. are the defaults. Raw numbers (as opposed to "2" or `\`2\``) are not acceptable as names because data.frames, like matrices, allow access via column numbers.

Comment: All of those comments are very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer where the `V1, V2, V3` names come from, check the source code of `'[<-.data.frame'`, line 139:

```
> deparse(`[<-.data.frame`)[139]
[1] "                new.cols <- paste0(\"V\", seq.int(from = nvars + "
```

As to why doesn't `e[1,10] = 10` work when `e` has only 3 columns, well, it simply doesn't. And if you think this contradicts your previous result (`d`), type `d[,4]` and see what happens.

Comment: Okay, between this answer and the comments, I think I have a better understanding.  It seems that, conceptually, at least, it is more useful to think of dataframes as a 2 dimensional array/vector (in a generic sense, not R, don't know if R uses those terms) that maintains  a mapping of names to indices for both rows and columns; the column names are accessible via names() and row names accessible via (wait for it...) row.names().  Looks like lists (as in list()) are similar but one dimensional.  Thanks for the help, lots of food for thought!

Comment: @retnuH Kind of. Data frames are meant to hold "two-dimensional" data structures, but they are quite literally lists. The two-dim aspect to them is simply an abstraction provided by the data structure and `[`. Data frames are literally a sub-class of lists where each element is required to have the same length. But run `is.list` on a data frame. Also, note that with some effort, you can break that abstraction. "Columns" of data frames can themselves be a list of data frames!